# How to change background color of a specific row in dataGrid in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe-animate

am using Adobe Animate in creating Air Desktop Application, in my application  I have a dataGrid component all I want to do is to change the color of a specific row depending on a cell value in it, i searched here but all i got was in Flex and mxml script,
this image is the datagrid i have
[image: default grid]
I want it to look like this:
[image: the look i want]
the color change depends on a value in a row called remain if it is not 0 the it change the row color
i want to do it in actionscript 3 inside the animate is it possible?
Thanx in advance...

Comment: I think you need a custom cell renderer: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/listClasses/CellRenderer.html

Comment: I didn' t understand how custom cell renderer works and the example did not worked for me I'll post what i get soon

Comment: It is indeed a complicated advanced subject, so there's a lot of effort ahead, good luck.

Comment: Thank you I'll try to find some examples or tutorials, actually I already searched with no success but I'll try again